# JSF Phase Listener redirect form not iframe

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, redirect, iframe

I have this PhaseListener that checks whether the user is still logged in or not after restoring a view. If the session has expired, then I want the entire form to redirect to the /login.jsf page but instead it only redirects the iframe within.

Basically, this is my code in the afterPhase() method:

```
if (isWebUserLogonOk(session)) {
  NavigationHandler nh = faces.getApplication.getNavigationHandler();
  nh.handleNavigation(faces, null, "loggedoff");
}
```

Where loggedoff is a navigation case that takes you to login.jsp page.

The redirect is done as expected but in this particular case I want it to be done for the entire form and not the iframe (JSF rookie talking here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to have a page (e.g. the login page) shown in an iFrame, a [javascript framekiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) should solve this.

Add the following code into your login pages `head` and try again:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(top != self) top.location.replace(location);
</script>
```

It easily reloads the current page as top page.

Hope it helps...